# How to use vectors in C++ using Xcode 7.3?

Tags: c++, xcode, vector

I'm studying from Bjarne Stroustroup's Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ (Second Ed.) At the moment I'm stuck at the vectors chapter, because of this error message in the Terminal:

```
fourth19.cpp:15:23: error: non-aggregate type 'std::vector<int>' cannot be
  initialized with an initializer list
std::vector <int> v = {5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8};    //vector of 6 ints
```

My/his code looks like this:

```
std::vector <int> v = {5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8};    //vector of 6 ints
std::cout<<v[0];
```

I didn't find anything that explains how to do this with Xcode 7+.

So if you have Xcode 7+ please write me down what to change and where to change that.

Comment: Somewhere in the project settings there should be an option to enable C++11, which is needed for initializing a vector like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default compiler flags for new Xcode projects is `-std=gnu++11`.

To check this:

1: Select your project in the Project Navigator (left-hand side of window, (Option-1 shows it if hidden).  It's the top item in the tree.

2: To the left of the search field, ensure that 'All' is selected rather than 'Basic'

3: Search for 'C++ Language Dialect' in the settings view.

4: It'll be in the section 'Apple LLVM 7.1 Language - C++'

Comment: I had a similar question, and I could find it easily using your instructions. Thanks. I'll upvote later on (votes exhausted for today).

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to enable c++14 support unless you have a pressing need not to.

Comment: Well, thank you for the advice. Actually it helped with a lot of other issues I faced with, however I still have the same error massage here.

Comment: Looking at again at your error, the compiler clearly knows what an initializer list is, but the standard library doesn't have one.   You might want to check you're building against clang libc++ rather than GNU libstdc++